# Django image modal display in web template

Tags: django, python-3.x, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, web-frameworks

I'm pretty new to Django Framework for web designing. In my web project, I have a template which contains a table coming from Oracle database and it is designed by django-tables2. In this table, I'm having a column which is linked to local images stored on my local machine. When user clicks the link in the table, an image is displaying on the same tab.

Now my question is can I display this image in a separate popup window or in new tab or in modal dialog box instead of displaying it in same tab?

I have referred online for this but in most cases results are for Form modal and not for media files and I could not figure it out that how those would be implemented in my case. Please, can anyone help me in this?

I'm using Django-Bootstrap for overall UI design, django-tables2 for table design, django-material for form design, Oracle database 11g, Python3.6 and Django 11.1.

My models.py is:

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
     p_key = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key = True)
     field1 = models.CharField(unique = True, max_length = 500)
     field2 = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null = True)
     .
     .
     field3 = models.FielField(max_length = 500, blank = True, null = True)
     foreign_key = models.ForeignKey('Table_Name', models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Accordingly, my tables.py is:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from django_tables2.utils import A
from my_app.models import ModelName

class TableName(tables.Table):
    p_key = tables.column(attrs = {'width' : '200px'})
    class Meta:
        model = ModelName
        fields = ('p_key', 'field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4')
        attrs = {'class' : 'table table-striped table-bordered'}
        order_by = 'p_key'
```

Accordingly, my views.py is:

```
from django.shortcuts import *
from .models import ModeName
from my_app.tables import TableName
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.template import Requestcontext
from django_tables2 import RequestConfig

def my_view(request):
    rec = ModelName.objects.all()
    table = TableName(rec)
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    table.paginate(page=request.GET.get('page', 1), per_page = 5)
    cnt = rec.count()
    context = {
        'table' : table,
        'count' : cnt,
    }
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

Accordingly, my html file 'template.html' is:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load bootstrap_themes %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% load querystring from django_tables2 %}
{% load title from django_tables2 %}
{% load static %}
{% load trans blocktrans from i18n %}

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/bootstrap.css" %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/bootstrap-theme.css" %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css" %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "django_tables2/bootstrap.css" %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/font-awesome.min.css" %}">

        <script src="{% static "js/jquery.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "js/jquery.min.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "js/bootstrap.js" %}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" align="center">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% render_table table %}
                <center>Total No. of Products are <strong style="font-size: 15px;">{{ count }}</strong></center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So this is my overall code structure. Among these files, from tables.py, I'm trying to display 'browse' field into the modal popup window. Please help me out. Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Share more details about the context returned to the template by your view. What data do you pass to `django-tables2`?

Comment: I have added my code as well... please help me out.. !